# Curl different response with browser/postman , PHP

Tags: php, curl

I try to crawl Twitter search using curl. last month it works but now it got 302 http response. but using browser and postman return 200 OK

this is my curl

```
$param = "?f=tweets&q=+LAPOR1708&src=typd&max_position=".$scrollCursor;
$url = "https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline".$param;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);        
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Accept: text/html"]);
dd(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

and this is my curl_getinfo
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNvQs.jpg)
and response using postman 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTb3m.jpg)

Comment: Don't use images for code snippets. Most people won't read them and you won't get help.

Comment: @ThomasSablik my bad. sorry.. I am new here. thank you very much

Comment: Same for the response and body content. Copy and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

A 302 response is a redirect.

Postman automatically follows redirects.

cURL does not.

This is normal. You should follow the redirect.

Comment: but the redirect go to [https://mobile.twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&q=+LAPOR1708&src=typd&max_position=](https://mobile.twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&q=+LAPOR1708&src=typd&max_position=) when using browser or postman not .

Answer (score 0):

Twitter’s Terms of Service prohibits crawling in this manner. You should use the official developer API to retrieve search results.

Comment: maybe, but i tray crawl using urlib in python. still works. thanks for comment

Comment: It may work but your account is at risk of being suspended for ignoring ToS. Just trying to help you.